# Flutter - Cursor keep blinking after change Form input

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a regular form on my APP, and when i load de screen no input is focused and no input has the cursor blinking...

Although, when run throw the inputs and fill them, or not, the cursor keeps blinking as i show on the image above:

[image]

The picture only show 3, but all of them are blinking. My point is that i need to keep only the focused input with the cursor blinking.

Heres the Form Code:

```
class RegisterView extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RegisterView> createState() => _RegisterViewState();
}

class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final FocusScopeNode _node = FocusScopeNode();
  String name = '';
  String email = '';
  String nif = '';
  String password = '';
  String _errorMessage = '';

  TextEditingController nameCtrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailCtrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nifCtrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordCtrl = TextEditingController();


  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _node.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserProvider userProvider =
        Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const CustomBackButton(),
        title: const Text('Register',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: kPrimaryColor,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: FocusScope(
              node: _node,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Please set your personal data:',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(_errorMessage,
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    TextFormField(
                      controller: nameCtrl,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[250],
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        hintText: 'Name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String data) {
                        setState(() {
                          name = data;
                        });
                      },
                      onEditingComplete: _node.nextFocus,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: emailCtrl,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[250],
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        hintText: 'Email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String data) {
                        setState(() {
                          email = data;
                        });
                      },
                      validator: (String? value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Required';
                        } else if (!emailRegex.hasMatch(value)) {
                          return 'Please set a valid email';
                        }
                      },
                      onEditingComplete: _node.nextFocus,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: nifCtrl,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[250],
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        hintText: 'NIF',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String data) {
                         setState(() {
                     nif = data;
                   });
                      },
                     
                      onEditingComplete: _node.nextFocus,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: passwordCtrl,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[250],
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String data) {
                        setState(() {
                          password = data;
                        });
                      },
                      validator: (String? value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Campo obrigatório';
                        } else if (value.length < 6) {
                          return 'Password deve conter pelo menos 6 caracteres';
                        }
                      },
                      onEditingComplete: _node.nextFocus,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    RoundedButton(
                      bgColor: kPrimaryColor,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          userProvider.isLoading
                              ? const SpinKitFadingCircle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 25.0,
                                )
                              : const Text(
                                  'Save',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  ),
                                ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          print('Ok to register');
                        }
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show some of your code and context please?

Comment: Sure. Code added.

Comment: Could this be because you are using only one focus node for multiple fields. Using one per text field might solve your problem.

Comment: It's a FocusScopeNode to the Form, not a FocusNode for all inputs.